# MVC Upload a file containing UserID

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET MVC project where i upload files in a SQL Server 2012 Database. I have created a table named "Conversion" with a relationship with the AspNetUsers Table. I've been able at this point to upload the file but i'm unable to add the UserID in my database.
This is my Conversion Class:

```
 public class Conversion
 {
    public int ConversionID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
 }
```

My UploadViewModel:

```
 public class UploadViewModels
{
    [DisplayName("Select File to Upload")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my UploadController:

```
 public class UploadController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new UploadViewModels();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UploadViewModels model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        Conversion conversion = new Conversion();

        byte[] uploadFile = new byte[model.File.InputStream.Length];
        model.File.InputStream.Read(uploadFile, 0, uploadFile.Length);

        conversion.FileName = model.File.FileName;
        conversion.File = uploadFile;
        //conversion.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserName();

        db.Conversions.Add(conversion);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Content("File Uploaded.");
    }
```

I tried with `conversion.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserName();` but it is not working, i got the following error:

> "An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code".

It happens at the `db.SaveChanges();`

If i'm not using the conversion.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserName(); I get a null in my database

Comment: _but it is not working_ is not a suitable explanation. What is happening? Is there an error? Is the value `null`?

Comment: You need to provide more detail that - what is the inner exception? And what is `User.Identity.GetUserName();` returning?

Comment: User.Identity.GetUserName(); is returning correctly the Username of the logged user! I verified it when debugging!

Answer (score 0):

I've been enable to make it work, i replaced

conversion.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserName();

with

conversion.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

I was getting the UserName instead of the UserId! It's working now!